# How to change focus out of iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Got some code which loads an `input` box, and then below this is an `iframe` with a `textarea`... Problem is I want the focus to be on the `input` box when the page loads, but it always jumps to the `textarea` because the iframe loads second...

How do I keep focus on the first element in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this inside the iframe code.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
window.parent.document.getElementById("idOfInput").focus();
</script>
```