# how to change focus out of IFrame

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have an IFrame with some buttons in it.  When the buttons are clicked, the parent DOM is manipulated (it's all in the same domain, so don't worry about the same-origin policy).

Since the user clicked on a button, the focus goes to the IFrame.  However, I'd like to move the focus back to the parent document (mostly due to [this FireFox problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501381/selection-changes-color-when-firefox-loses-focus)).

How can I do this?

**Edit:** I've created a [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paleozogt/emDLZ/) that shows the problem.  While `focus()` seems to work if you call it on parent form elements, it doesn't work in general.  As you can see from the js-fiddle there are no form elements in my parent document.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511311/how-to-change-focus-out-of-iframe

Comment: Have you tried addressing the parent document by using `top`?

Comment: @rt2800 It's close, but not a duplicate. In that question he's trying to keep focus in an input element. I'm trying to do it in general and it seems that the answer for the input element case doesn't work in general.

Comment: @daniel0mullins How do you mean? top.focus()?

Comment: @daniel0mullins document.getElementById gets the right dom element.  how would accessing it via top change things? its the same dom element.

Comment: Not sure it would...just ruling out all possibilities. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the focus back to the outer window from inside the iframe, focussing the outer window itself is unlikely to give any visual feedback to the user, so it is better to focus a known form element in the outer page.

You can do this as follows:

### outer.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Outer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="inner.html">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

### inner.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Inner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="innerForm">
      <input type="button" id="innerButton" value="Inner button" />
    </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // When we click the inner button...
    document.getElementById('innerButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
      /*
       * Do whatever you need to do here
       */

      // Focus the parent
      parent.focus();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: But my page doesn't have any form elements. :/

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can just skip the call to `getElementById`, and instead call `parent.document.focus()`.

As far as I know, however, some browsers (notably Firefox) impose rules over calling focus() on a window, based on user settings.

Comment: Both Chrome and FireFox complain that document.focus is not a function. :(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - just `parent.focus()` will suffice. It's a method of `window`, not `document`. Have updated answer to match :)

Comment: ah, that works. unfortunately, you're right about FF. i found a bug for it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=554039)

Answer (score 1):

Make an eleemnt on your page and call this at some point after focus is set to the IFrame:

```
document.getElementById("myElementId").focus();
```

That will set the focus back to the body and out of the IFrame.

Comment: using focus() doesn't work. i've edited my question to link to a js-fiddle that shows the problem.